# Removing words from text c#

Tags: c#

I need to remove from my sentence away the words i have.I need to remove all the words from 10th word with using "Remove". I need to remove it from this sentence:

```
string stavek = "Today is a very beautifull day";
```

Comment: what do you need to remove from that string?

Comment: Provide an example of before and after

Comment: this sentence has only 6 words, so you're done.

Answer (score 6):

```
string newString = stavek.Remove(10);
```

Or if you need to remove certain number of characters then:

`string.Remove` has an overload which takes position and number of elements to be removed, you can do:

```
string stavek = "Today is a very beautifull day";
int position = 10;
string newString = stavek.Remove(position, stavek.Length - position);
```

Its better if you check for `Length` so that you don't get an exception for invalid range.

Comment: Well, this will get first 10 characters, we can use `Substring` with more ease.

Comment: @user3013951 your question is too bad. You said `10th word` not `10th character`